# Make checkbox and a textbox Readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my javascript code,is there a way to make checkbox and textbox readonly?

```
//display textboxes and checkbox when condition is true.
if($$("id").value =="something"){
       document.getElementById("textboxl").style.display="";
        document.getElementById("chkbox1").style.display="";
        document.getElementById("textbox2").style.display="";
        document.getElementById("chkbox2").style.disable="";
    }
```

I have to display and then disable it(i mean make it readonly).

Comment: (Among other things)I added the `jQuery` tag as it looks like you're using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

```
element.readOnly = true
```

---

**Set `readonly` with:**

```
$('#chkbox1').prop('readonly', true);
```

Or:

```
$('#chkbox1').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

**display can be done with:**

```
$('#chkbox1').show();
```

Or with:

```
$("#chkbox1").css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: :thanks for the reply..i`m sorry for informing this late,plz check out the question i have changed.

Comment: :We are using '$' as a function just to avoid rewriting 'document.getElementById'.

Comment: $("AprEmail2").disabled=true; $("chkApp2").disabled=true; this thing worked for me